# Re-distributing Buckets

Tags: algorithms

Let’s set I have 3 buckets of coins.

The buckets are A, B and C.

Coins are debited and credited to each bucket.

It is possible for the A bucket to go negative. In such a case, I want to deduct funds that are positive from the B bucket, and then the C bucket, if necessary, aka redistribution, to make the A bucket less negative as possible.

Example:

A= -5
B= 3
C= 3

Re-distributing would result in:

A=0
B=0
C=1

What algorithms already exist to figure out redistribution, ie knowing how much to deduct from B and C to make a negative A as close to 0 as possible?

Comment: Take as many from $B$ as needed.  If all of $B$ is insufficient, start taking from $C$.  If $A+B+C<0$ then you can't do it at all (or perhaps you mean to say that in that case you go to $(A+B+C,0,0)$ even if the first entry is negative).

Comment: I think what you're describing is a fractional knapsack with equal weights.

Comment: Clarification requested: If $~(a,b,c) = (-10,10,100),~$ should the redistribution result in $~(a,b,c) = (0,0,100) ~?~$  Similarly, if $~(a,b,c) = (-200,10,100),~$ should the redistribution result in $~(a,b,c) = (-90,0,0) ~?$

Comment: Yes @user2661923

Comment: Then, unless I am mistaken, the comment of @lulu nails it.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms would be called "Pick B", or "Pick C":
$$f = \{(A+1,B-1,C) | A<0,B>0\}$$, or
$$g = \{(A+1,B,C-1) | A<0,C>0\}$$.
Then repeatly applying f and g will give the answer.

Comment: B and C should be decremented, no?

Comment: yup. (negative A messed things up) -> fixed